# Error in the MICE library of R to impute missing data

Tags: r, dataframe

When I use the MICE function, it marks the following error

> Error in data.frame(it = s$it, im = s$im, dep = s$dep, meth = if (is.null(meth)) s$meth else meth, : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1

my code is the following

```
library(mice)
dat <- read.csv(url('https:/ /goo.gl/4DYzru'), header=TRUE, sep=",")# whithout space

 # Missing data are simulated in the Cholesterol column
missing <- rbinom(n= nrow(dat),size= 1, prob= 0.24)
dat$Cholesterol <- with(dat, ifelse(BMI >= 30&missing==1, NA, Cholesterol))

imputed<- mice(dat) #Here marks error
imp <- complete(imputed)
```

R version: 4.1.1
mice Library Version: 3.13.0

Comment: In R version 4.0.3 and mice 3.13.0, it works

Comment: Works fine for me R4.1.1 / mice3.13.0. Try in a vanilla R session.